# How do I obtain the coordinate vector of this set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have 2 sets,

$S=${$(3,0,7,5),(6,5,5,6),(5,2,5,-4)$}

$T=${$(2,1,3,3),(1,1,0,-1),(0,1,-1,2)$}.

The first part of the question required me to find the transition matrix P from S to T. The second part of the question required me to obtain $(w)_S$ given that w is a vector in $ℝ^4$ and $(w)_T = (3,1,4)$.

What I have done so far is find the matrix P using Gauss Jordan Elimination, and this is the result I've gotten: $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 1\\-1 & 2 & 3\\-1 & 1 & 2\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The example given in my textbook tells me that the way to find $(w)_S$ is to find $P^{-1}$ so that I can use matrix multiplication of $P^{-1}$ and $(w)_T$ to find $(w)_S$. But P is not invertible, so that method can't be used.

Is there any way around this problem? Am I allowed to take out the zero row or is there any other way to find $(w)_S$ other than this method?

Comment: Why do you think you need to find the inverse of a matrix here?  A matrix which is not square is never invertible, and if you remove rows from it, then it is no longer the same matrix...

Comment: @JMoravitz Because I cannot conceive of any other way to find $(w)_S$.

Comment: If you wish to solve a system $Ax = b$, if it so happens that $A$ is invertible then you may of course find $x$ uniquely by using $x = A^{-1}b$.  Of course, there are many examples of matrices $A$ which are not invertible, but it is still an interesting and important problem to find the solution *set*.  One common technique is to row reduce the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ and interpret the results correctly.  Depending on the results, you might still find a unique solution, you might find there are no solutions, or you might even find there are infinitely many solutions and what they look like.

Comment: *Every* introductory text on linear algebra will have more details on how to accomplish this.